# Xamarin.Forms: iOS Camera doenst work, Gallery works ok (Android, both works)

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms

since my iPhone Simulator has no camera, it is impossible to debug this on my simulator. But I have a physical device, however, with those stupid provisioning profiles, I am only able to send release versions to my actual iPhone 7, which means it doesnt return debug info.

However, with the help of TRY CATCH I was able to pinpoint when the actual iPhone crashes: it is this line of code:

```
        file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreCameraMediaOptions
        {
            Directory = "Sample",
            Name = "test.jpg"
        });
```

The whole code looks like this:

```
    await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();

    Plugin.Media.Abstractions.MediaFile file = null;

    try
    {
        file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreCameraMediaOptions
        {
            Directory = "Sample",
            Name = "test.jpg"
        });



    }
    catch
    {
        await DisplayAlert("1", ":( No camera available.", "OK");
    }

    if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsCameraAvailable || !CrossMedia.Current.IsTakePhotoSupported)
    {
        await DisplayAlert("No Camera", ":( No camera available.", "OK");
        return;
    }

    if (file == null)
        return;
```

Since it runs into the catch block here, I know it is the abolev line that throws the error.

This is the james montamagno plugin.

Can you guys help me out here? Might this be a permission problem?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding this to info.plist:

```
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app needs access to the camera to take photos.</string>
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app needs access to photos.</string>
```

Solved the issue!

Comment: Glad to hear that you have solved your issue now, please remember to mark your reply as answer, it is helpful to others to find this answer, thanks.

Comment: Sure, but I cant accept it until tomorrow. Also, someone downvoted. What did I do wrong here?

Comment: It is ok, having no problem.